# Google Maps Routes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, spatial

I want to save cycling routes from **Google Maps** in **MySQL**. A route can be combination of [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines) and [directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). Searching if a route is in a given area is needed. What are the possible methods and their pros and cons?

[Spatial Extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html) looks very convenient, but I can't find anywhere how to process [WKT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-wkt-format.html) in **JavaScript/PHP**.

Comment: Just a question, are you able to use postgreSQL? Because it has spatial types built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the JSON representation of the directions in one column, and the spatial representation in another (i.e. polyline).

That way you can use spatial queries for bounding box, distance queries, etc but still have the convenience of the JSON.

Please make sure you comply with the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3), though - look at section 10.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a couple of tables will work well here...

First, one to store info about the route such as expected time of completion, etc. This table gives each route a unique id.

Second, a table which stores individual lat and lon coordinates along with the id of the route along with a number representing where this point is located in the sequence of points to define the entire polyline. Rendering the line is a matter of pulling the coordinates for the route you're intested in, ordering then sequentially and feeding that to the maps api. Your directions could be stored with the pertinent points.

Searching for routes in the area is a matter of searching for points in the db with matching or near matching lat and lon coords and returning the route id, then rendering the route.